# How to populate combobox with record and print selected corresponding records

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox

Trying to populate `tkinter combobox` with spaecific records from my tuple 
then when i select the record in the combobox to print i want to get the
corresponding record which were not populated in the combobox.

It populate the `combobox` like `1 ben journalism 18`.But i want to poulate it like this `ben` and then when i select  it print like `1 ben journalism 18`.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk



rows = ((1, 'ben', 'journalism', 18), (2, 'sally', 'performing arts', 22),(3,"dan","information technology",32))


def selected(event=None):
    print(cb.get()) # print selected record in other column


root = Tk()

cb = ttk.Combobox(root)
cache = list()
for row in rows:
    cache.append(row)
    cb['values'] = cache

cb.pack()
cb.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", selected)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few minor changes should fix it for you. First, I'm assuming rows is a list of lists like [[1, 'ben', 'journalism', 18], [2, 'sally', 'performing arts', 22]...]

```
def selected(event=None):
    # Find the row that contains the selected student's name
    for row in rows:
        if cb.get() in row:
            # Found it. Print it.
            print(row)
            break

for row in rows:
    # Insert just the student name into combobox
    cache.append(row[1])
cb['values'] = cache
```